# Plum tree set fruit but now it's all gone

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, fruit-drop

My plum tree - 4 years old but pruned incorrectly in 2nd year so was hoping for fruit this year - blossomed beautifully and tiny green fruits appeared.  Now a few weeks later I can't see any fruit on the tree.  It's a victoria plum, planted in an allotment.  A couple of plots away there is also a plum tree.

Comment: Got squirrels? Does the other plum have fruit?

Comment: what part of the world are you in? did you see the fallen fruitlets on the ground?

Comment: I've seen something similar in Bristol (England) this year.  No frsots later than the blossom, loads of tiny fruit, and they've just disappeared.  Presumably they were still tiny when they fell off leaving no trace on the ground. Now I've got about one plum left.  I do get squirrels in the garden but I've never seen them in the plum tree or on the fence behind it (fan-trained tree).

Comment: Chris H - I was amazed to read your message.
I am also in Bristol My 3 year old Victoria plum was covered in green plums
about 1 cm diameter. They VANISHED over the last 2 days.
No sign of them under the tree. I just dont know where they went.
I was wondering about Pigeons - but they would have to hover to get them !
some of the branches would not support a Squirrel or Pigeon.
Maybe they all dropped off and something has eaten them from the ground ?
Colin in Shirehampton

Answer (score 1):

What insecticide / fungicide schedule are you using ? You will need at least 3 sprays after dormant oil , if you expect much fruit. I have had surprising success with peaches with no spray ( the squirrels and coons loved them ). However, I had two varieties of plum trees about 50 ft away and I have not seen any fruit larger than 1/2 " diameter in 20 years ( no spray). Apparently some insect larva eat the fruit as it starts to grow. In another location , I grew many types of tree fruit  using sprays with good success.  Red currants and raspberries will produce well with no sprays. Also hazel nuts do well without spray.

Comment: Figs are good with no spray if you are warm enough.